# get back deleted .svn folder

Tags: svn, repository, undelete

On my server I have subversion installed, but I accidently removed the .svn folder from the
root so the folder is no more under version control.

When i try to make a new checkout, I get an error

```
svn: 'repo' is already a working copy for a different URL
```

Thats probably because .svn is still available in sub-folders.

How can I get back the .svn folder so that I have subversion available?

Comment: Is it a local server or remote. In some cases you can do Ctrl+Z and it will reproduce the files deleted by mistake. Basically this is an UNDO shortcut.

Comment: Unless you have uncommitted changes, just delete the folder altogether and do a clean checkout. If you have uncommitted changes, checkout to a different folder, then merge.

Comment: +1.  Good question. I did the same thing last week and ended up deleting EVERYTHING and doing a fresh checkout.  I'd also like to know a less ridiculous way of correcting such a mistake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try to checkout your repo in a fresh folder, then copy the root .svn directory into your old root folder, it should do the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete everything and checkout a fresh copy. Or you could try letting everything in place and checkout with a depth of 1. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html